# Ultrafilter Quantifier Check $\forall_{\mathcal{U}}x\ \forall_{\mathcal{U}}y\ p(x)$ and $\forall_{\mathcal{U}}x\ \forall_{\mathcal{U}}y\ p(y)$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and $U\in\mathcal{U}$. We write $\forall_{\mathcal{U}}x\ p(x)$ to mean $\{x\ |\ p(x)\}\in\mathcal{U}$, where $p(x)$ is some logical statement.

Am I correct in thinking that

$$
\forall_{\mathcal{U}}x\ \forall_{\mathcal{U}}y\ (x\in U)\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \forall_{\mathcal{U}}x\ \forall_{\mathcal{U}}y\ (y\in U)\ \ \ 
$$

are both true?

The first one because the value of $y$ does not affect the statement $x\in U$, so $x\in\mathcal{U}$ is true for all $y\in \mathbb{N}\in\mathcal{U}$.

The second for essentially the same reasons but with $x$'s and $y$'s reversed.

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: The two statements that you're comparing both say that $U\in\mathcal U$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, just wanted to confirm my understanding.